# wordpress sidebar issue with wp_list_categories showing NO Categories

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

So on my wordpress install. I am trying to display category list in the sidebar but having issue with wp_list_categories function. There are handful of categories in the system but this function just prints "NO Categories".

Can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: I take you're in the PHP code.  Have you tried searching the code for "NO Categories"?  That would lead you to the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have at least 1 Post in every category you want to display
2. `wp_list_categories` should be outside of the wordpress LOOP. You'll probably need to provide the sidebar's code before the LOOP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the right function, but you need to adjust a parameter for it. You are getting

> No Categories

simply because the categories defined in the WordPress taxonomy have no posts assigned to them.

Try passing the `hide_empty` argument to `wp_list_categories( $args );` 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0');
```

This example will show all categories regardless of their post count.

Reference the [wp_list_categories Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) page for more help.

Answer (score 0):

to use **inside loop**, use **`get_posts()`** instead of `get_categories()`;

```
$cat_ID = 239;

$array =  get_posts('child_of'=> $cat_ID ,    'post_type'=> 'post');    $out='';
foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
    $out .= '<li class="manual_posts"><a href="'.get_permalink($value->ID).'">'.$value->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
echo $out;
```